# emacs: "click" on "links" in command line emacs

Tags: macos, command-line, emacs, gui

In some emacs documentation there are underlined texts that resemble links. For instance, by `M-x list-packages` we get the following:
[image: document with links]

In some GUI version of Emacs like [Emacs For Mac OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com/) (but not xterm), we can actually click on the links and get something like:
[image]

I wonder whether that's possible for command line? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Upvoted for cluing me in to the existence of ELPA -- thanks! I've been using Emacs for a couple of years now, and I'm still discovering new capabilities almost daily.

Comment: @AaronMiller Yeah, Emacs is fairly easy to get hands on, but there are always a million ways to optimize workflow. It's such an almighty platform :)

Comment: Yeah, all it needs now is a bootloader. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not natively possible (as far as I know) to click on a link in a terminal Emacs session and have Emacs treat it as it would in a session running under X. However, in most (if not all) cases where Emacs offers a hyperlink, `RET` while point is on the link will have the same effect as a click would.

The alternative would be finding a way for the terminal to pass click events to Emacs, and for Emacs to properly interpret such events once received. I've no doubt that's possible, but I haven't been able to find a way to do it; in the meantime, it should be almost as fast (if not faster) to do something like e.g.

```
C-s adapti RET RET
```

to isearch straight to the 'adaptive-wrap' link, then complete the search (the first `RET`) and activate the link (the second).

Comment: Great, `RET` is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks.

Comment: Sure! Always glad to help out another Emacs user.